# Triangle Inequality Problem...

Tags: geometry

In triangle $ABC$, the medians $\overline{AD}$, $\overline{BE}$, and $\overline{CF}$ concur at the centroid $G$.
[image: Diagram]

(a) Prove that $AD < (AB + AC)/2$.

(b) Let $P=AB+AC+BC$ be the perimeter of $\triangle ABC.$ Prove that

$\dfrac{3P}{4} < AD + BE + CF < P.$

Here's my work so far:

[image: My Work So Far]

I just need help on the last part of parts (a) and (b).

Comment: Isn't there something like those $1/3 - 2/3$ ratios as how medians are divided into one another?

Comment: Yes, $AG=\dfrac{2}{3} \cdot AD$

Comment: DE is a midline of the triangle.  What do you know about midlines?

Comment: Isn't the midline equal to half the base of the triangle? $DE=AF?$

Comment: $CG + BG>CB, AG + BG > AB,$ etc.$\implies  2(AG+BG+ CG)>P, AG = \frac 23 AD,$ etc. $ \frac 43(AD+BE+ CF)>P.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) Notice. $\overline {DE}\ ||\ \overline {AB}$ and $=\overline {AB}/2$. And $\overline {AE}=\overline {AC}/2$ $\therefore$By triangle law ,$\overline {AE} +\overline {DE}\gt \overline {AD}$

b) (1st inequality only) $$\overline {AG}+\overline {BG}\gt \overline {AB}$$$$\implies{2\over 3}(\overline {AD}+\overline {BE})\gt \overline {AB}$$

Similarly do for $\overline {BC}$ and $\overline {AC}$.

$\therefore {2\over 3}(2\times(\overline {AD}+\overline {BE}+\overline {CF}))\gt P$

Comment: @Anonymous Please upvote if you liked my answer :-)

Comment: I like your answer :-)